# Compute conditional probability for a decision analysis network

Tags: conditional-probability, decision-theory, decision-trees

I have to resolve an exercise for decision analysis network.

I have the following decision tree for that decision analysis network:

> $$\begin{array}{l} G&\to&Y&\to&D&\to&X&\to&U%
> \end{array}$$

**G**, **Y** and **X** are chance nodes.
**D** is a decision node.
**U** is an utility node.

I don't need to compute probability of **D** because it is a decision node (this is why probability of **X** node is $P(x|y)$ instead of $P(x|d)$.

I know $P(x)$, $P(y|x)$ and $P(g)$ and I need to compute $P(y|g)$

How can I compute it?